# Getting tag of object from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` used inside a custom class that subclasses `UIView`. Within that scrollview, I have added several other custom objects (all subclassing `UIView` as well) like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;

    for (int count = 0; count < ColorSchemeCount; count++) {
        //Check for next page first
        [self managePageAdditions];

        //Set up the scheme
        ColorScheme *scheme = [[ColorScheme alloc]
                               initWithFrame:[self determineSchemeCircleFrameFromCount:pageCheck]
                               title:[self getColorSchemeTitleFromIndex:pageCheck]
                               colors:[self getColorSchemeFromIndex:pageCheck]];
        scheme.tag = pageCheck;
        tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(schemeTouchedAtIndex:)];
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [scheme addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:scheme];

        //See if next pass requires a new page or not
        if(pageCheck > 0) needsNextPage = (pageCheck % kSchemesPerPage == 0);
        needsNextPage ? pageCheck = 0 : pageCheck++;
    }
```

And then I try to see the `ColorScheme`'s tag to respond accordingly:

```
- (void)schemeTouchedAtIndex:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    CGPoint touchPointInSuperview = [gesture locationInView:self.scrollView];
    ColorScheme *touchedView = (ColorScheme *)[self.scrollView hitTest:touchPointInSuperview withEvent:nil];

    NSLog(@"%li", (long)touchedView.tag);
}
```

And no matter what I seem to do, **it always logs the tag as zero**.

A couple of observations:

- I can confirm the tags are being set properly, and all the `ColorScheme` are being added just fine.
- I also have the `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO` so the `UIScrollView` won't swallow all the touches.
- In the `locationInView` I have tried using `self` instead of `self.scrollView` to no luck. Again, the code where this resides is in a class subclassing `UIView`.

Stumped on this one, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what is pageCheck...? set tag as a count instead of pageCheck.

Comment: pageCheck is an int that is incremented in the loop but is also coupled to other things, which is why I am not using "count". When it pageCheck is a multiple of 6, I need that to go back to 0, which I cannot easily do using "count", hence the iVar pageCheck

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
-(void)schemeTouchedAtIndex:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
NSLog(@"%ld", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

Since your gestures are hooked to the ColorScheme object its less hacky to grab the view from the gesture recognizer itself.

Comment: Thanks!!! Geez, I knew there had to be something easy to do this. For some reason when I looked in the docs, I didn't that a gesture had a view as a property. Great solution

Comment: Sometimes I forget to look at the parent classes and wonder where the hell the methods are.